# Animation using images with React Native?

Tags: react-native

Im trying to do an animation with React Native, that requires network images to download first. Basically I have a `ListView` of images, when a user clicks on a list item I need get the clicked image and do some animation with it. I am able to do this with an image from file/app, but the problem is with network images.

**Code(cut some code for brevity):**

```
    const data = [
       {image:"http://someimage.com/2.jpg"},
       {image:"http://someimage.com/1.jpg"}
    ];

    class ImageAnimate extends Component{
       constructor() {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
           dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
           pageY: new Animated.Value(0)
           image: ""  // image source to animate
           ....
         }
       }

      openListing(data) {
         this.setState({image: data.image}); // image to use from ListView
         Animated.timing(this.state.pageY, {duration: 1000, toValue: -200, useNativeDriver: true}).start()
      }

     render() {
         return <View> 
                   <ListView ... /> // ListView of images
                   <Animated.Image source={{uri: this.state.image}} />
               </View>
     }
    }
```

I appreciate that network images need time to download, I guess what Im trying to ask is if i can re-use images that have already been downloaded with the ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the real question is whether or not you can download images to the device locally and use them. Have a look at [this library](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) (if you don't like that it's no longer maintained try [this](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) one). If you use `react-native-fs` you easily use its `downloadFile` function as follows:

```
var options = {
      fromUrl: $(IMAGE_URL),
      toFile: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/($DESIRED_FILENAME)"
    }
    RNFS.downloadFile(options).promise.then(res => {
      this.setState({downloadComplete: true});
      console.log("File download completed at " + options.toFile);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Error downloading file: ", err);
    });
```

You should then be able to pass the local path, ie `RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/($FILENAME)"`, as the `source.uri` property for your `Image` or `Animated.Image` components